# Android: invoking web services using SOAP

Tags: android

I am using a web service which is returning xml schema. I want to invoke it through SOAP. I have coded it but i am not getting any output. Can anybody please help me out?

my web service is:

http://dev.sigwp.org/WikipediaOntologyAPIv4/Service.asmx?WSDL

Comment: I am not able to paste my code here. Can you give me your email id?

Answer (score 0):

it is not very clear from your question what you really want but if you want to use soap web service from Android you can follow this tutorial

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/88b6e5/how-to-call-web-service-in-android-using-soap/

Comment: I followed the tutorial. In that tutorial, they are returning string as response. In my web service, they are returning xml schema. How to display that?

Answer (score 0):

I used the below to make a soap request for login. Modify the same accodring to your needs. Make sure you have the latest soap jar file included in your project lib.Also have a look at this tutorial. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v9EowBVgwSo.

```
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject("NameSpace", "MethodName");//
    loginreq.setValue("<LoginReq>" 
                        +"<nickName>"+name+"</nickName>" 
                        +"<password>"+pass+"</password>" 
                        +"<IMEI>"+mImei+"</IMEI>" 
                        +"<location>" 
                        +"<latitude>"+lati+"</latitude>"
                        +"<longitude>"+longi+"</longitude>"
                        +"</location>" 
                        +"</LoginReq>");//my requirement was to send request in this format.
   PropertyInfo loginreq = new PropertyInfo();
            loginreq.name="LoginReq";
            loginreq.type=String.class;
            request.addProperty(loginreq);  //sending request.
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelop = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelop.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            System.out.println("Request is"+request); 

        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new   HttpTransportSE ("http://bugs.medalsystems.com:8080/ThirdEye/ThirdEyeWebService?wsdl");//your wsdl link
        androidHttpTransport.debug=true;

        try
        {
        androidHttpTransport.call("http://service.medal.org/ThirdEyeWebService/LoginRequest", envelop);
        SoapObject response=(SoapObject) envelop.bodyIn;
        System.out.println("Response is......"+response.toString());
   System.out.println("Response is......"+response.toString());

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf =DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputSource is = new InputSource();
        is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(response.getProperty(0).toString()));

        Document doc = db.parse(is);//parse xml
        NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("StandardResp");

        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) 
            {

              Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);

              NodeList rc = element.getElementsByTagName("respCode").item(0).getChildNodes();//get value form respCode tag
              ResponseCode = ((Node) rc.item(0)).getNodeValue();
              System.out.println("Respone Code...."+ResponseCode);

              NodeList mess =  element.getElementsByTagName("message").item(0).getChildNodes();
              Message = ((Node) mess.item(0)).getNodeValue();
              System.out.println("Message....."+Message);

              NodeList sess =  element.getElementsByTagName("sessionId").item(0).getChildNodes();
              SessionIdlin = ((Node) sess.item(0)).getNodeValue();
              System.out.println("Session Id....."+SessionIdlin); 

            }

        }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
         {
      e.printStackTrace();
       }
```

[Parsing XML schema java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11408652/parsing-xml-schema-java).

Comment: I followed the tutorial. In that tutorial, they are returning string as response. In my web service, they are returning xml schema. How to display that?

Comment: you will have to parse the xml using sax or dom parser

Comment: check the above. i have edited. i too had a similar requirement where in response was in xml tags. I used dom parser since there were not many tags. Choose your own parser according to your requirements. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Raghunandan.. Just now, I saw my logcat and it is showing some soap fault.. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode><faultstring>Server was unable to process request. ---&gt; Fill: SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized.</faultstring><detail /></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>

Comment: 1)http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266774/how-to-resolve-soap-fault-in-ksoap2. 2)http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865502/android-2-1-and-ksoap2-android-assembly-2-4-soapfault-error. Version Mismatch i guess. have a look at the link